How does a Boltzmann distribution curve look like?
I am doing an MC simulation of Argon particles using LJ pair potential. I need to verify if my simulation source code is working properly.
The following was my conversation with my professor yesterday.

1:26 PM Student Hello. If I create a histogram of 50 bins of total-energies from 100k steps of MC simulation of LJ particles, it should look like a Boltzmann-curve right?
1:29 PM Professor Yes, but nobody knows, how a Boltzmann-curve looks like. It's not a Gaussian distribution
1:30 PM Student Then, how can I verify that my MC simulation is working perfectly? Autocorrelation only?
1:31 PM Professor You should make the E(T) curve and check if: energy increases with temperature. then you observe phase transition

He says, nobody knows, how a Boltzmann-curve looks like. It's not a Gaussian distribution.
However, by Googling, I found many plots of the Boltzmann distribution curve.
For example, https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-Boltzmann-distribution-curves-representing-reactions-of-X-and-Y-in-Q9_fig3_371811622

So, why did my professor say that "nobody knows how a Boltzmann curve looks like?"

This sounds superficially like a communication error. Are there any other details here that would be useful?

@controlgroup, Are there any other details here that would be useful? --- I don't think so.

Is this about the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, or the Boltzmann distribution? Because the image you've included looks just like a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. These are two different things.

I wonder if your professor’s intended meaning is that other right-skewed distributions could be mistaken for a Boltzmann distribution, so the “look” alone is unconvincing.

What is known as Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution (which may be sometimes abbreviated as Boltzmann distribution) is the distribution of particle speeds in an ideal gas. One could also recast it as a distribution of energies (as in @agaminon answer), using that $E=mv^2/2$, i.e., relying on the fact that particles in the ideal gas a considered as non-interacting (apart from the collisions, responsible for the establishing the thermodynamic equilibrium.) These are the curves that are routinely found in the internet (and indeed, this is just a particular case of the chi-squared distribution.)
Boltzmann/Gibbs distribution is the distribution of microstate probabilities arising from using the canonical ensemble. It can be also formulated as a distribution of energies (see this answer.) Boltzmannn/Gibbs distribution is much more general than the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, since it is not restricted to non-interacting/ideal gas. Even if we know the form of the particle-particle potential, obtaining distribution in a closed form may be challenging or impossible. However, as the comment by @agaminon states, this might be actually possible for the LJ potential:

Yes, under a Lennard-Jones potential the energy distribution of the particles follows a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.

The professor might be unaware about this (or forgotten or disagree), so it is worth discussing this article with them (after reading it) - it could significantly advance your project or at least help you to understand it much better.

The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is a distribution for the molecular speeds or energies based on assumptions from the kinetic theory of gases. In terms of the energy, it is
$$ f(E) = 2\sqrt{\frac{E}{\pi}}\left(\frac{1}{k_BT} \right)^{3/2}\exp\left(-\frac{E}{k_BT}\right).$$
Which is a well known function. I think this must be some kind of miscommunication.

Yes, under a Lennard-Jones potential the energy distribution of the particles follows a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.

Add this comment and link to your answer, plz.
